# How do I combine Javascript Classes and Callbacks properly?

Tags: javascript, class, callback

This isn't my actual code (hopefully obviously), but it's a very short example that demonstrates the problem.

I'm writing a class with a method that accepts a callback as an argument. When the method finishes, it should call the callback.

```
class Demo {
    constructor() {
        this.method1();
    }

    method1() {
        console.log("Method1");
        this.method2(this.method1);
    }

    method2(onDone) {
        console.log("Method2");
        onDone();
    }
}

new Demo();
```

So I want this to jump back and forth between calling `method1` and `method2`. If it worked properly, I should end up with a stack overflow, but instead what happens is this:

```
Method1
Method2
Method1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'method2' of undefined
  at method1 (demo.js:8)
  at Demo.method2 (demo.js:13)
  at Demo.method1 (demo.js:8)
  at new Demo (demo.js:3)
```

Somehow, when we enter `method1` the second time its been forgotten that `this` is an instance of `Demo`. I tried replacing `onDone()` in `method2` with `this.onDone()` but then it completely fails to find `onDone` (which makes sense - `onDone` is the name of an argument, not the name of a member of `Demo`.)

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: That question doesn't involve javascript's `class` keyword. It may have the same root issue, but it's certainly not a duplicate of this one.

Comment: Use `this.method2(this.method1.bind(this));` or use `onDone.call(this);`

Comment: @4castle - Perfect, thank you!